# Cron expression throwing java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scheduler, cronexpression

I am using springs [CronTrigger](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.html) class to build a trigger with following cron expression

```
0 10 12 ? 1/1 6#3
```

Which i think is a valid one that will schedule a Task to run on

> Third friday of every month at 12:10 pm

This expression is giving expected output when I validated it on [cronmaker.com](http://www.cronmaker.com/).But while trying to build a trigger using this expression as:

```
CronTrigger trigger=new CronTrigger("0 10 12 ? 1/1 6#3");
```

Its throwing me `java.lang.NumberFormatException For input string: "6#3"`.I am not getting what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean` instead of `CronTrigger`. 
Also your cron expression should be like this `0 10 12 ? * 6#3`

Comment: I can't use CronTriggerBean because I am using ThreadPoolTaskScheduler  which takes only Trigger and its implementations in schedule method.And I don't think 1/1 is a problem because i am building cron expression dynamically so it could be 1/2 1/3.And exception also occuring for the dayofWeek expression.

Comment: Can you paste more code that you are doing related to this? I tried with my expression but in CrontriggerBean and it worked.

Comment: Also `CronTriggerBean` is a subclass of `CronTrigger`..So i don't think it would be a problem..see [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/CronTriggerBean.html)

Comment: And check [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/573160/Spring/Cron-expression-Spring-Task-scheduler) as well :)

Comment: I can't use CronTriggerBean because i am using org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger and why should i have to add all the quartz library for using just one class,That would be an overkill...Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Then you need to change the cron expression dude..check [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26717/discussion-between-dangling-piyush-and-anubhab)

Answer (score 0):

I've just come with a workaround that should work. You can check it here - [How to write Cron expression to execute a trigger on 3rd Sunday of every month at 11 PM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357235/how-to-write-cron-expression-to-execute-a-trigger-on-3rd-sunday-of-every-month-a/19447517#19447517)