# How to write Cron expression to execute a trigger on 3rd Sunday of every month at 11 PM?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to fire a trigger on 3rd Sunday of every month. In cron expression I used 
 cron="0 0 23 ? * 1#3" 
But its gives me Exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1#3"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.getRange(CronSequenceGenerator.java:324)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.setNumberHits(CronSequenceGenerator.java:297)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.setDays(CronSequenceGenerator.java:275)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.parse(CronSequenceGenerator.java:241)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronSequenceGenerator.<init>(CronSequenceGenerator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger.<init>(CronTrigger.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger.<init>(CronTrigger.java:44)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTaskRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(ScheduledTaskRegistrar.java:188)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:209)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:1)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is code I am trying

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 23 ? * 1#3") // Fire at 11 PM on the third sunday of every month
    public void sendReportNotCreatedNotificationToStudent() throws Exception{
        scheduleNotificationIntf.sendScheduleNotificationToStudent("createReportRemainder.html");
    }
```

Please anyone tell about this error. How can I achieve this Cron expression.

Comment: Any reason you are trying Java and not basic shell?

Comment: Its a web application. I am trying to start a scheduler on 3rd sunday 11 pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that that the cron entry syntax you are using is not supported by Spring.  Apparently, Spring 3.x only supports "classical" cron entry formats ... as documented in the [`crontab(5)` manual entry](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/).  Note that "x#y" syntax is not supported.  See also the javadoc for the [Spring `CronSequenceGenerator` class](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html).

But the syntax you are using appears to be the [Quartz crontab expression](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) syntax.

---

**UPDATE**

A brief examination of the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.context/3.2.1/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.java#CronSequenceGenerator.setNumberHits%28java.util.BitSet,java.lang.String,int,int%29) for `CronSequenceGenerator` in Spring 3.2.1 has no sign of support for "#" in field 6.  Indeed, the line numbers match up with your stacktrace, so I'm confident that the following answer is definitive.

> How can I achieve this Cron expression.

You can't with Spring.  Spring does not support that kind of Cron expression.  If you want to use that kind of expression, you will have to switch to using the Quartz scheduler.

Comment: Despite this being the accepted answer, the workaround below definitely works. I'm placing the comment here just in case someone feels like giving up...

Answer (score 5):

I might come a bit late, but I happened to have the same exact issue, and I've come with a workaround. I've tested it, and it works! This expression:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 23 1-7 * WED") // First wednesday of the month at 23:00
```

Will run for the first wednesday of the month. The explanation is simple: the first wednesday will always be a day within the 1-7 range, so if we filter the day of the month to be between 1 and 7, and the week day to be Wednesday, we have it done :) I haven't tested it, but using the same logic these expressions should be working as well:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 23 8-14 * WED") // Second wednesday of the month at 23:00
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 23 15-21 * WED") // Third wednesday of the month at 23:00
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 23 22-28 * WED") // Fourth wednesday of the month at 23:00
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 23 29-31 * WED") // Fifth wednesday of the month at 23:00
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you should try this expression `0 0 12 ? 1/1 SUN#3 *`

Comment: I tried this but still same exception NumberFormatException: For input string: "0#3"

Answer (score -1):

Try using quartz scheduler instead of spring scheduler. 
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06